# Javascript return not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

I have this code:

```
function get_id_from_coords (x, y)
{
    x = parseInt(x);
    y = parseInt(y);

    if (x < 0)
    {
        x = (x + 6) * 60;
    }
    else
    {
        x = (x + 5) * 60;
    }
    if (y < 0)
    {
        y = (y + 6) * 60;
    }
    else
    {
        y = (y + 5) * 60;
    }

    $('#planets').children().each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('x') == x) {
            if ($(this).attr('y') == y) {
                alert (parseInt($(this).attr('id')));
                return parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
            }
        }
    });
}
alert(get_id_from_coords(x, y));
```

However, from this code I get two popups:
First, from inside the function, I get the proper value (like 63), but then, when I alert the return value, I just get undefined.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` defined outside of the function?

Comment: Yes, and they work properly inside the function

Comment: I'm pretty sure `return` isn't broken

Comment: Icyrock's solution looks good - your returns aren't set up correctly.

Comment: @SnackerSWE, for `if (y < 0){y = (y + 6) * 60;}else{y = (y + 5) * 60;}`, consider shrinking it into `y = (y+5+(y<0))*60`. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get undefined as you function doesn't return - the last statement is a call to `each` function and it's not a `return` statement. If you put a return, e.g.

```
...
return $('#planets').children().each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('x') == x) {
        if ($(this).attr('y') == y) {
            alert (parseInt($(this).attr('id')));
            return parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
        }
    }
});
```

it will return something - in this case, based on the docs:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

  ```
  The method returns its first argument, the object that was iterated.
  ```

it will return the children of `#planets`.

If you want to find some value specifically using `each`, then you can do something like this:

```
...
val toRet;
$('#planets').children().each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('x') == x) {
        if ($(this).attr('y') == y) {
            toRet = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
        }
    }
});
return toRet;
```

Comment: @SnackerSWE - Maybe you should consider to accept the answer?